# The range of $b - c \sin x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> The function $f(x)$ is defined by:
>
> $$f(x) = b - c\sin x, 0\le x \le 360$$
>
> where $b$ and $c$ are constants, $c > 0$.
>
> Find the range of $f(x)$, in terms of $b$ and $c$.

I substituted the lower limit of the domain and got $b-c(0) = b$ and the upper limit, giving $b-c(0) = b$. Why cant I find the range this way?

Comment: Hint: The range of $\sin(x)$ is $[-1,1]$

Answer (score 2):

The range is the set of all values assumed by the function. The sine function oscillates between $-1$ and $1$, so $b - c\sin(x)$ oscillates between $b - c$ and $b + c$.  I assume you are operating in "degree mode" here; what you see is one complete period of the function.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your approach is that $\sin x$ is not monotonic on $[0,360]$. Therefore, we can't claim that the extremal values of $b-c \sin x$ are attained at the boundaries of the intervals.

On the other hand, $\sin 360+x = \sin x$, so all possible values of $\sin x$ are attained in the given interval $[0,360]$.

Now, what is the largest possible value of $\sin x$? What is the smallest? How do these relate to the range of $b - c \sin x$? Can all intermediate values be attained? If so, why?